# How do I test cells in an array column for number or string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a multi dimentional array where I want to sort one of the columns.

I found this method in another question which works fine as long as you know the type (only numbers) of the cell values.

```
var arr = [
  [12, 'AAA', '3ab'],
  [12, 'BBB', '5ac'],
  [12, 'CCC', '9tt'],
  [28, 'DDD', 'cpo'],
  [18, 'CCC', 'ert'],
  [12, 'DDD', 'jet'],
  [18, 'CCC', 'o55'],
  [28, 'DDD', 'y65'],
  [28, 'DDD', '549'],
  [58, 'BBB', '772'],
  [68, 'BBB', '999'],
  [78, 'BBB', '3p5']
];

arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a[0]-b[0]
});
```

--What I want to do is test the cell values for a number or a string before sorting.
--How is this done?

I think I need to give some more information - sorry for my clumsy explanation.

**1)** *I want to sort only one of the column at a time.*

**2)** *Before sorting I want to test if the content of the specific column is a number or a string   because the sorting is done differently -

a[0]-b[0]

vs

a[0] lt b[0]    (lt = less than)

The easiest way would properly be to say that all the cells in the column are defined as a string and then test to see if the are all numbers instead.*

**3)** If they all are numbers I would use the a[0]-b[0] sorting instead of the a[0]

Hope this explains it better than before.

Comment: `var isString = function(val){ return typeof val == "string"; }
var isNumber = function(val){ return !isNaN(val); }`

You could utilise both of these functions

Comment: @benhowdle89: `isNaN` does not check if a value is numeric. It checks if a value is `NaN`.

Comment: @benhowdle89 You should use `typeof "number"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort by the first value, then the second value in those arrays, you'll need something like this:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    var first = a[0] - b[0];
    return (first === 0 ? (a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : (a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : 0)) : first); 
});
// Result:
[[12,"AAA"],[12,"BBB"],[12,"CCC"],[12,"DDD"],[18,"CCC"],[18,"CCC"],[28,"DDD"],[28,"DDD"],[28,"DDD"],[58,"BBB"],[68,"BBB"],[78,"BBB"]]
```

Or, without the ternary shorthand:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    var first = a[0] - b[0]; // Difference between the 2 numeric values (a[0], b[0])
    if (first === 0) {       // If the numeric values are equal
        if (a[1] > b[1]) {   // Return a order depending on the string values (a[1], b[1])
            return 1;
        }
        if (a[1] < b[1]) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0; // The string values are the same, so return `0`
    }
    return first; // The numeric values are not the same, so return the difference as sort result.
});
// Result:
[[12,"AAA"],[12,"BBB"],[12,"CCC"],[12,"DDD"],[18,"CCC"],[18,"CCC"],[28,"DDD"],[28,"DDD"],[28,"DDD"],[58,"BBB"],[68,"BBB"],[78,"BBB"]]
```

Runnable sample:

```js
var arr = [[12,'AAA'],[12,'BBB'],[12,'CCC'],[28,'DDD'],[18,'CCC'],[12,'DDD'],[18,'CCC'],[28,'DDD'],[28,'DDD'],[58,'BBB'],[68,'BBB'],[78,'BBB']];
var sorted = arr.sort(function(a,b){
    var first=a[0]-b[0];
    return(first===0?(a[1]>b[1]?1:(a[1]<b[1]?-1:0)):first);
})
alert(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can check that a value is numeric using this function

```
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: `parseFloat("123abc")` returns `123`, which is not `NaN`.

Comment: @Cerbrus it doesn't matter , the function must check 
if the entry value is a  number and it
always  return correct value